# Can't use some Alt+ keyboard shortcuts in Google Sheets like I did in Excel on some computers

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, google-chrome, google-spreadsheets

In Excel there are some <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts like:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>: paste special value only
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>: insert a new row

In Google Sheets, they can also be used. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for example, I see this popup at the bottom:

[image: "Shortcut key pressed: Alt + I"]

I know that I can toggle compatible key shortcuts in Google Sheets like this:

[image: Switch: "Enable compatible spreadsheet shortcuts"]

With this turned on, I can use the above-mentioned <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts however, on some of my computers (Windows 10) turning this option on or off has no effect and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts listed above cannot be used. There is nothing special about this computer: it's running Windows 10 latest version, latest Chrome.

Comment: Do you need to pree Alt+Fn?

Comment: Mysterious! I can only guess... region settings, keyboard settings, accessibility settings, account privileges, strange local/group policy about program access to alt buttons?, try run as administrator, try firefox, try another keyboard (laptop vs usb). Weird 32 vs 64 bit issue in compiled chrome binary. Try 32 bit chrome installer.

Comment: No need for ALt-FN @Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

LastPass hotkeys were interfering with Google Sheet hotkeys.
I don't know how to disable all hotkeys from LP in Chrome. However, you can choose to disable only certain hotkeys.

Right click LP icon and choose Account Options - Extension Preferences.
[image]
[image]

Choose Hotkeys. Here you can remove the troublesome hotkey (usually Alt-I) and click Save.
[image]